# how to make entire row of list view clickable?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, row, contactscontract

I am trying to make multiple contact picker for my application. I am using a custom layout with checkbox to select multiple contact. The problem i am facing is that in order to select any particular contact i need to click exactly on the checkbox, if i click on other part of the row the checkbox doesn't get ticked. How can i make sure that wherever the user click in the entire row the checkbox gets ticked.

**activity_contacts_picker.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnShow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show Selected" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnShow" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**custcontactview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="5.0px"
android:paddingLeft="5.0px"
android:paddingTop="5.0px" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtContactName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15.0dip"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtContactNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtContactName"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15.0dip"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ContactsPicker.java**

```
public class ContactsPicker extends ListActivity {

protected Object mActionMode;
public int selectedItem = -1;
private Button btnShowContacts;
private ListView myListView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts_picker);
    myListView = getListView();
    btnShowContacts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
    btnShowContacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String name = null;
            String number = null;
            long[] ids = myListView.getCheckedItemIds();
            for (long id : ids) {
                Cursor contact = getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = ?", new String[] { id + "" }, null);
                while (contact.moveToNext()) {
                    name = contact.getString(contact
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    number = contact.getString(contact
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Name: " + name + "\n" + "Number: " + number,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = buildData();
    String[] from = { "Name", "Phone" };
    int[] to = { R.id.txtContactName, R.id.txtContactNumber };
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
            R.layout.custcontactview, from, to);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> buildData() {
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    list.clear();
    Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
    while (people.moveToNext()) {
        String contactName = people.getString(people
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String contactId = people.getString(people
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String hasPhone = people
                .getString(people
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
        if ((Integer.parseInt(hasPhone) > 0)) {
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                            + " = " + contactId,
                    null,
                    "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                            + ") ASC");
            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                String phoneNumber = phones
                        .getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                Map<String, String> NamePhoneType = new HashMap<String, String>();
                NamePhoneType.put("Name", contactName);
                NamePhoneType.put("Phone", phoneNumber);
                list.add(NamePhoneType);
            }
            phones.close();
        }
    }
    people.close();
    //startManagingCursor(people);
    return list;
}
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding this attribute to your ListView

android:clickable="true"

Also, I don't see where you're setting Touch/Click listener to your myListView.

Answer (score 6):

Try changing the the checkbox layout width to fill parent as follows,

```
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Guess it will work for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I would add a click listener to the textfield and if clicked change the state of the checkbox to its opposite state (clicked <-> unclicked)

Answer (score 1):

First you can use CheckedTextView instead CheckBox. Maybe only this work.

or

Try set CheckBox focusable="false", if don't work then focusable in all View from your XML layout.

Answer (score 0):

if you use button/checkbox/radiobutton on your list item then list item is not clickable

you may solve your problem by [click here](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=525)